# mkdir failed if the folder name is same with a existing file

Tags: go

I tried to make a folder with a statement below:
"os.MkdirAll("./src/database/test01/bucket",os.ModePerm)"

There is a file ("./src/database  note: not a folder) already existed in my project, so the os.MkdirAll  won't create the folder successfully.
How can I create a path in like this.

Comment: "How can I create a path in like this." -- You can't. Every file (and on practically every file system, a directory counts as a file) must have a unique name.

Comment: You'll need to write your own "force" `mkdir`, inspecting each filepath part for any collisions & if so deleting them.

Answer (score 2):

The operating system (Windows, Linux, etc) prevent this.

More specifically, it is a restriction in the filesystems they use (FAT, NTFS, EXT, etc)

You cannot create a subdirectory with the same name as an existing file.